# How to get standard error from fitlm command

Tags: matlab

I am using fitlm for my regression and am using the command `lm.Coefficients.Estimate(1)` to the estimate for the intercept. How can I do the same but for the standard error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fitlm` returns a [`LinearModel` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel-class.html) which has a number of properties to determine the goodness of the fit. All of these properties can be accessed using the dot notation.

You can compute the standard error for each coefficient from these properties as shown in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/coefficient-standard-errors-and-confidence-intervals.html#bty1mfy-1).

```
standardErrors = diag(sqrt(lm.CoefficientCovariance));
```

**Update**

If you want the overall standard error of the fit, that is typically defined as the square root of the mean squared error. We can compute that:

```
stdErr = sqrt(lm.MSE);
```

Comment: The command gives me all the standard errors. How can I get only one standard error out?

Comment: Yes, but if I only want the standard error for example the first parameter. How would that look?

Comment: @Orongo The first one will return the standard error for *each* parameter. If you want the standard error for the first parameter, then just use `standardErrors(1)`

Comment: lm.Coefficients.standardErrors(1) only gives me an error

Comment: @Orongo Yes of course it does. That isn't what I typed.... Look at the first piece of code above. It defines a variable called `standardErrors`. You want to index into that.